# What am i doing wrong in this procedure query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not so familiar with MySQL, i tried creating a MySQL procedure that SELECTS two fields from a table, assign them to a variable then use the value of those variables to update another field in a different table, so far, this is the code i have but when i run it i get this error:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @amnt = (SELECT`initial_payment`FROM`ph`WHERE`payment_status`= 'unconf' at line 5`

This is my code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE check_for_days()
BEGIN 
    SET @i = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ph` WHERE `payment_status` = 'unconfirmed' && TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `date_paired`, NOW()) > 2) ;

    label1:WHILE @i>0
        SET @amnt = (SELECT `initial_payment` FROM `ph` WHERE `payment_status` = 'unconfirmed' && TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `date_paired`, NOW()) > 2 LIMIT 1);
        SET @id_to_cred = (SELECT `to_pay_id` FROM `ph` WHERE `payment_status` = 'unconfirmed' && TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `date_paired`, NOW()) > 2 LIMIT 1);
        UPDATE `gh` SET `remaining_to_get` = + @amnt WHERE `u_id` = @id_to_cred;
        DELETE FROM `ph` WHERE `payment_status` = 'unconfirmed' && TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, `date_paired`, NOW()) > 2 LIMIT 1;
        SET @i = @i - 1;
    END WHILE label1;
END 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: it's `set @i := ...`

Comment: Ask *another* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the stored procedure is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you syntax error:

```
label1:WHILE @i>0 
  SET @amnt
```

where is `DO`

```
label1:WHILE @i>0 DO 
      SET @amnt`
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was my solution.